# How to weave a pytorch tensor

Tags: numpy, pytorch, data-science, data-manipulation, tensor

I have two matrices

```
A = torch.tensor([[1,1,1,1,1],
                  [1,1,1,1,1],
                  [1,1,1,1,1]])

B = torch.tensor([[2,2,2,2,2],
                  [2,2,2,2,2],
                  [2,2,2,2,2]]
```

I want to concatenate two matrices in a way that matric C becomes:

```
C = torch.tensor([[1,2,1,2,1,2,1,2],
                  [1,2,1,2,1,2,1,2],
                  [1,2,1,2,1,2,1,2]])
```

I think it can be possible if A converts to:

```
 torch.tensor([[1,0,1,0,1,0,1,0],
               [1,0,1,0,1,0,1,0],
               [1,0,1,0,1,0,1,0]])
```

and B converts to:

```
torch.tensor([[0,2,0,2,0,2,0,2],
              [0,2,0,2,0,2,0,2],
              [0,2,0,2,0,2,0,2]])
```

and then add them up. Is there any way to do so? thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve this with a combination of transpose, stack and transposing back:

1. Stack transposed tensors:

   ```
   >>> torch.stack((A.T, B.T), 1)
   tensor([[[1, 1, 1],
            [2, 2, 2]],

           [[1, 1, 1],
            [2, 2, 2]],

           [[1, 1, 1],
            [2, 2, 2]],

           [[1, 1, 1],
            [2, 2, 2]],

           [[1, 1, 1],
            [2, 2, 2]]])
   ```
2. Transpose again:

   ```
   >>> torch.stack((A.T, B.T), 1).transpose(1, 2)
   tensor([[[1, 2],
            [1, 2],
            [1, 2]],

           [[1, 2],
            [1, 2],
            [1, 2]],

           [[1, 2],
            [1, 2],
            [1, 2]],

           [[1, 2],
            [1, 2],
            [1, 2]],

           [[1, 2],
            [1, 2],
            [1, 2]]])
   ```
3. Reshape to the final form:

   ```
   >>> torch.stack((A.T, B.T), 1).transpose(1, 2).reshape(A.size(0), A.size(1)*2)
   tensor([[1, 2, 1, 2, 1, 2, 1, 2, 1, 2],
           [1, 2, 1, 2, 1, 2, 1, 2, 1, 2],
           [1, 2, 1, 2, 1, 2, 1, 2, 1, 2]])
   ```